# Testing different screen resolutions in Universal (iPad,iPhone,iPod) app development

Tags: ios-simulator, screen-resolution, universal, screen-size

I notice when submitting a Universal app to the app store, there are various screen resolutions to support.  I think iPhone/iPod: 320x460, 320x480, 640x960 and iPad 768x1024.

When I specify Universal app development in Xcode, the simulator has a resolution of 320x480.  To view 768x1024 screen resolution, I can change the target setting to iPad, but how to test 320x460 and 640x960 resolutions?

My default solution is to target iPad, and manually hack my code, e.g.: `SCREEN_WIDTH=640, SCREEN_HEIGHT=960;` but surely there should be a setting on the simulator for this!?

In a related question, is there any way to get screen captures off the simulator (apart from command-shift-3 and cropping the resulting image)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

640x960 is an iPhone 4. You can simply select "iPhone 4" in the simulator device menu. You'll notice everything is twice as big (unless your computer has a small screen).

The iPhone 4 will still say its screen is 320x480 according to [`[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772647/simulator-iphone-retina-has-wrong-screen-resolution) for a discussion.

460x320 is the standard iPhone/iPod Touch screen minus the size of the status bar. You don't need to support it separately from 480x320.

Note: The "iPhone 4" option has been renamed "iPhone (Retina)" in recent simulator versions.

I don't think there is a better way to get screen captures off the simulator.

Comment: OK thanks.  I think I see what is happening now.  I don't have "iPhone 4" in the device menu--just "iPhone Retina".  I guess my simulator version (4.2 (235)) must be old.  Know any (better) way to get a screen capture off the simulator?

Comment: In a follow-up to this, I have tried to update my Xcode/simulator version but the installer just hangs.  Looks like that is a separate issue though.

Comment: OK, I just downloaded the latest SDK from apple, and installed without a problem, but I still don't have iPhone 4 in the device menu on the simulator.  I guess I'll start another thread about this.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 The "iPhone 4" option was renamed "iPhone (Retina)" in the simulator (which I hadn't noticed when I posted my answer).

Comment: My Code:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 SCREEN_WIDTH=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
 SCREEN_HEIGHT=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;
 NSLog(@"w:%f h:%f",SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
...} displays "w:320.000000 h:480.000000" with the simulator set to iPhone Retina... ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772647/simulator-iphone-retina-has-wrong-screen-resolution/ for related discussion, and a really, really helpful answer.

Comment: @graham, I've up-voted your answer.  I still want to know "is there any way to get screen captures off the simulator (apart from command-shift-3 and cropping the resulting image)?"  My guess is simply "No".  This would be a useful feature because the app store wants me to include screen-shots on different devices (but I only have an iPad).  Anyhow--this is holding me back from accepting your answer.

Comment: OK @graham, I improved your answer to the point where I thought I could accept it.